# Consolidate Hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a simple ruby newbie question. How can I consolidate two hashes:

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "a" => 100, "c" => 200 }
```

into this one:

```
h3 = {{ "a" => 100, "b" => 200 },{ "a" => 100, "c" => 200 }}
```

Comment: That `h3` thing isn't a hash. Hashes are always `thingA => thingB`, whereas that is `{thingA, thingB}`. Do you really want an array, maybe? Or do you want to merge it into `{"a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => 200}`? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

What you have in `h3` is an array of hashes (except with hash delimeters), which you can get like this:

```
h3 = [h1, h2]
```

If you want to combine the hashes, you can call [`merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

```
h3 = h1.merge(h2)
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200, "c"=>200}
```